# How to get the latest value in getchar()?

Tags: c, getchar

i am entering input using `getchar()` function and when i press the enter after entering the input i get the value of c inside loop as good which i entered but when i enter a non-digit and the loop breaks ... the latest value of i entered is a `new line` which has ASCII value as 10.

how could i possibly retain the digit value . All i want is `c` to have the digit value after the loop breaks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
main()
{
  int c =0;
  while(isdigit(c=getchar()))
  {
    printf("c is : %c\n",c);
  }
   printf("latest value of c(ASCII) is : %d\n",c);
}
```

Comment: add a lag variable `int last` and update this from c as you go..

Comment: Since you now know that the problem is the newline was not properly consumed/skipped over,  You could be checking (in the while() statement) to see if the character input is a newline.  (which is what is currently exiting the loop) then read the final integer, perhaps with scanf()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way todo this is to add a lag variable and write to this from c every iteration :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int c = '0', lastchar = 0;
  while(isdigit(c))
  {
    if(!lastchar)
    {   
      printf("c is : %c\n",c);
    }   
    lastchar = c;
    c = getchar();
  }
  printf("latest value of c(ASCII) is : %d\n",lastchar);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
  int c = 0, last = 0;
  while(isdigit(c=getchar()))
  {
    printf("c is : %c\n",c);
    last = c;
  }
   if (!last)
          printf("latest value of c(ASCII) is : %d\n", last);
   else
          printf("No digits were entered\n");
   return 0;
}
```

You could do this.

Comment: You should really have main return an int both explicitly in the signature as well as in the body.

Comment: @martin Yes, that's how I usually do it. This is just the OP's code, edited.

Comment: You are free to fix the code, some people honor this.